# Is it still branchless sorting if I place a conditional in a while loop?

Tags: c, sorting, branch

I am currently looking into branchless (or branch free) sorting. I was thinking about how I would implement an insertion sort, sorting integers and came up with the following:

```
int a, b, t;
for (a = 1; a < arr_size; i++) {
    t = arr[a];
    b = a - 1;
    while (b >= 0 && arr[b] > t) {
        arr[1 + b] = arr[b];
        b--;
    }
    arr[1 + b] = t;
}
```

My question is, is this still branchless? I do see a performance increase to if I would use if statements but I am not sure if we can call this branch free. Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: No, not branch free at all unfortunately. `while (condition) { do stuff; }` is the same as `while (1) { if (condition) { do stuff; } else break; }`.

Comment: So it doesn't help at all with branch mispredictions?

Comment: As I understand it, branchless sorting can only be done for fixed-size sets of data. If you use a loop with a variable for the number of elements, it's not branchless, because you have the conditional branch back to the beginning of the loop.

Comment: @Barmar Counting sort would be branchless apart from the outer loop condition (which will be mispredicted once or twice). OP's example appears to be a comparison sort though, and I don't think that can be branchless, as you say.

Comment: @SimondeGans no it does not. It's still a branch. Whether you write it as a `while` loop or as something else. Branch prediction is done regardless by the CPU at the hardware level. The control condition in your `for()` is easily predictable since it's going to be always true and then false only at the end (the branch is still there anyway of course). The result of the condition in your `while` statement cannot be easily predicted though. It leads to *two* branches (because of the `&&`) every iteration, the second of which is hard to predict.

Comment: @SimondeGans: Notwithstanding Marco Bonnelli’s comments, `while (condition) { do stuff; }` may be considered branchless in the ways that matter. Processors may have instructions optimized for implementing loops controlled by simple iteration up to a limit, and compilers know to use wudh instructions so that the branch is predicted to continue the loop (so that the prediction fails at most once per use of the loop, on the last iteration). If looking for a “branchless” sort is for the purpose of performance, then you may consider this sufficient…

Comment: … It is the harder-to-predict branches inside the loop that may be a problem. If you are looking for “branchless” for some other purpose, such as to satisfy a professor’s definition for a class assignment, then you need to determine the definition of “branchless” for your purpose. Note that an absolutely branchless loop is not feasible if the number of elements to be sorted, or at least a close limit on the number, is not known in advance, since, otherwise, adapting the behavior to a number of elements determined at run-time requires a branch at some point.

Comment: Adding mine and to @EricPostpischil's comment: the problem is the `arr[b] > t` in the condition, which makes it harder to predict the branch. Simple loops such as `for (i = 0; i < N; i++)` or `while (b-- > 0)` lead to easy-to-predict branches.

Comment: @EricPostpischil , Marco Bonelli Thanks for the clear explanations. It does make sense that this is indeed not "branchless". It is basically to prove the speed difference by implementing the same sorting algorithm branchless vs the branched version of it. I will define a fixed size for this purpose. You covered it pretty well. Now I am wondering if insertion sort is even possible to do branchless as you will always need comparisons. I'll continue my search, thanks for the amazing answers :).

Comment: Typo: “wudh” should be “such”.

Answer (score 0):

The code is not branchless, since it contains two conditions. Each of the loops creates a branch.

The outer loop checks:

```c
if (i < arr_size) {
  doLoopBlock();
} else {
  break();
}
```

The inner loop checks:

```c
if (b >= 0 && arr[b] > t) {
  doLoopBlock();
} else {
  break();
}
```

The CPU is sometimes able to predict the outcome of a condition. In that case, it's about as performant as a branchless variant. In the outer loop, for example, the condition is predictable and has one misprediction at the end.

The compiler may be able to optimize the generated code, for example if `arr_size` is known at compile-time it can "unroll" the loop. It will remove the loop completely and generate consecutive code for every i.

For the inner loop, though, you'd have to come up with a logic formula which works without the loop. That's often a hard problem, sometimes an unsolvable one. At that point it makes more sense to try other optimizations than removing branches, or look for another algorithm altogether which is easier to optimize.